# Drupal Entity Reference based on custom field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, feed, entityreference

I hope that this question has not yet been answered, but I searched through lots of topics and I didn't find an answer.

Here is the problem: I'm trying to link two nodes from different content types, and I'd like to use another field than the Title of the other node as a reference.

The reason I dont want to use the node's Title is because I'm currently building a website for a movie theater. I'm using Feeds to import movies and movie times from a xml file. These are both represented by their own content type.
Each movie has its own unique ID picked from a database, and this is the field I'd like to use for joining two nodes.

The aim is to display a movie alongside its movie times (they are more than one movie 
time's node for one movie, because a movie can be seen in 3D/non 3D mode, VO/translated...).

When I'm trying to use Entity Reference, I can't find a way to fill (for example) a text field with this unique movie's ID, in order to use it as a relationship in Views.

I hope my problem and question are both understandable (excuse my English...), and that some of you could help me to find a solution.
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by grouping fields based on Film ID. 
I'll just have a bit of templating to make in order to wrap my view's output to wrap all fields, but it shouldn't be a problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the entity reference selection method to use a view instead of the "simple". You have to have views installed.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further ?
I tried it but I didn't really get how to set it up.  

The view I will use should render the movie ID ? (by the way, thanks for your answer)